# GoogleAPIのrefresh_tokenの取得制限

Tags: oauth, google-api

GoogleAPIでoauth2.0を使用する際、ユーザー同意時にrefresh_tokenを受け取っていると思いますが、1つのAPIから発行可能なrefresh_tokenの制限ってあるんでしょうか？

もし、refresh_tokenの発行に制限が設けられているのだとしたら詳細を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは、はじめまして。本家にも回答がありましたが、

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135980/google-api-refresh-token-limit

下記の公式ドキュメントにGoogle APIのリフレッシュトークンの仕様が記載されています

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration

There is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per user account per client. If the limit is reached, creating a new refresh token automatically invalidates the oldest refresh token without warning.

各クライアントのユーザーアカウントごとに最新の50件が保持され、制限に達すると最も古いものが警告なしに無効化されるとのことです